# Dictionary returns null value without any reason

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, nsdictionary

Here my JSON format for which got from web-service as a response,

```
"popups":
 [
 {
  "sowhat": 
            {
                "isAvailable": "TRUE",
                "hasVideo": "FALSE",
                "hasAudio": "TRUE",
                "content": "<p><span><span><strong>SO WHAT?</strong></span></span></p><p><span><span> Belief shapes behaviour. But the question is, &lsquo;How much?&rsquo; How much does the promised return of Jesus shape your behaviour from day to day? Do you find yourself thinking about it very much or maybe doubting it from time to time? Perhaps we can liken it to the final whistle or siren of a grand final. The whistle ends the match but in a much greater way the return of Jesus ends world history as we know it. His return ushers in the complete rule of God&rsquo;s kingdom which began when Jesus came to earth. Does this reality shape what you do each day? Are you ready for his return?</span></span></p>"
            }
 },
 {
  "questions": 
            {
                "isAvailable": "TRUE",
                "hasVideo": "FALSE",
                "hasAudio": "FALSE",
                "content": "<p><span><span><strong>QUESTIONS </strong></span></span></p><ol><li><p><span><span>Read Luke 1:1-4. How is Acts both similar and different to Luke&rsquo;s gospel?</span></span></p></li><li><p><span><span>What key Christian truths are mentioned in Acts 1:1-11?</span></span></p></li><li><p><span><span>How is the Holy Spirit related to the task assigned to the apostles (verse 8)?</span></span></p></li><li><p><span><span>If verse 8 hints at the broad outline of the book of Acts, where might the gospel arrive at by the conclusion of the book?</span></span></p></li><li><p><span><span>What does the choosing of Matthias demonstrate about the disciples&rsquo; attitude to the Scriptures?</span></span></p></li></ol>"
            }
  }
]
```

Here my code which i use to parse in dictionary

```
  NSDictionary *popupContents = [readingPlanContents valueForKeyPath:@"popups"];
  //SoWhatPopup
  NSDictionary *soWhatPopup = [popupContents valueForKey:@"sowhat"];
  soWhatPopupAvlbl=[soWhatPopup valueForKey:@"isAvailable"];
  NSString *soWhatVdeo=[soWhatPopup valueForKey:@"hasVideo"];
  NSString *soWhatAdio=[soWhatPopup valueForKey:@"hasAudio"];
  soWhatCntn=[soWhatPopup valueForKey:@"content"];
  NSLog(@"soWhatVdeo:%@ ",soWhatVdeo);
  NSLog(@"soWhatAdio:%@ ",soWhatAdio);
  NSLog(@"soWhatCntn:%@ ",soWhatCntn);
  NSLog(@"soWhatPopupAvlbl:%@ ",soWhatPopupAvlbl);
//QuestionPopup
  NSDictionary *questPopup = [popupContents valueForKeyPath:@"questions"];
  questPopupAvlbl=[questPopup valueForKey:@"isAvailable"];
  NSString *questVdeo=[questPopup valueForKey:@"hasVideo"];
  NSString *questAdio=[questPopup valueForKey:@"hasAudio"];
  questCntn=[questPopup valueForKey:@"content"];
  NSLog(@"Avaliable:%@ Content:%@",questPopupAvlbl,questCntn);
```

The Log value returns the following text

```
soWhatVdeo:
(
FALSE,
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"
) 

2014-11-05 17:24:21.044 StandFirm[3655:100200] soWhatAdio:(
TRUE,
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"

 2014-11-05 17:24:21.044 StandFirm[3655:100200] soWhatCntn:(
 "<p><span><span><strong>SO WHAT?</strong></span></span></p><p><span><span> Belief shapes behaviour. But the question is, &lsquo;How much?&rsquo; How much does the promised return of Jesus shape your behaviour from day to day? Do you find yourself thinking about it very much or maybe doubting it from time to time? Perhaps we can liken it to the final whistle or siren of a grand final. The whistle ends the match but in a much greater way the return of Jesus ends world history as we know it. His return ushers in the complete rule of God&rsquo;s kingdom which began when Jesus came to earth. Does this reality shape what you do each day? Are you ready for his return?</span></span></p>",
 "<null>",
 "<null>",
 "<null>",
 "<null>"
 ) 
2014-11-05 17:24:21.045 StandFirm[3655:100200] soWhatPopupAvlbl:(
TRUE,
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"
)
```

I dont understand why its keep show so many null value instead of showing the current value.Whats wrong with my code?How to get only the value ?Please correct my code

Comment: Have you parse JSON response?

Comment: Lets just say about "popups". It returns an array, Not a dictionary. Save this values to `NSArray` and then got further.

Comment: @Kampai is absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'popups` in your JSON is actually an array not a dictionary.

The first element in the array is a dictionary so this would be valid

```
NSDictionary *popupContents = [readingPlanContents valueForKeyPath:@"popups"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change first line of your code. Here `readingPlanContents` returns an array not a dictionary. So you need to create an `NSArray` variable for this and use for loop to get inner values. See below code.

```
    NSArray *popupContents = [readingPlanContents valueForKeyPath:@"popups"];

    for (NSDictionary *details in popupContents) {
        NSDictionary *soWhatPopup = [details valueForKey:@"sowhat"];
        soWhatPopupAvlbl=[soWhatPopup valueForKey:@"isAvailable"];
        //....

        // And so on
    }
```

Comment: Content is coming but still while looping it shows null value